# Unable to send email with Mac Mail via Mailgun

Tags: mail.app

Beginning in July of 2015, I've been unable to send mail using the Mailgun SMTP server using Mac Mail. To add a Mailgun account, I go to Mail > Preferences and under Account Information > Outgoing Mail Server (SMTP)

[image]

I choose the Edit SMTP Server List option. I select the options shown in the images.

[image]
[image]

When I hit OK, the account description in the Outgoing Mail Server (SMTP) briefly changes so that the "(Offline)" suffix is removed, but then it is quickly added back and I can't send with that account.

As suggested by Mailgun at https://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-sending.html#send-via-smtp,

[image]

I tried sending with swaks and was successful, though I had to change the password provided by Mailgun's example.

Answer (score 1):

Go to: Connection Doctor in the Windows menu item...

[image]

Then enable the log, or select show details to see if anything in the log helps you to see what the issue is...

[image]

Comment: Thanks; why didn't I do this?! I tried this after reading your post; I'm told the username or password is incorrect, but still haven't been able to fix it. I can't mark this as correct b/c it hasn't fixed the problem, but thank you for help.

Comment: Normally you don't use the username password of your account but the API key... Have you checked that?